# Config not visible on Parse Server Dashboard?

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

So I've got a successful Parse-Server up and running on Heroku, and a functioning Parse-Server-Dashboard as well.

My issue is that through Parse-Server-Dashboard I'm not able to see the Config section. I've been searching endlessly, but I haven't been able to find any resources on this issue.

I've set my Config Var on Heroku PARSE_EXPERIMENTAL_CONFIG_ENABLED = 1, which allows me to get the config client-side just fine, but I still can't see it in dashboard.

Dashboard is V 1.0.15, and Parse-Sever is V 2.1.6

Here's what I'm seeing:

[image: my browser]

Here's (something similar to) what I want to see:

[image: what I want from my browser]

Cheers,

Comment: When you run it on your local machine you do see the config ?

Comment: How does your server's config look like?

Comment: @RanHassid, nope, it's never showed up for me.

Comment: Hi @AndreyGordeev, are you asking about my index.js file, or the actual global config that I'm trying to fetch/edit.

Comment: Can you try to access your config by adding  /config after you application name in parse-dashboard link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update parse-dashboard to the latest version as well as parse-server (you're running 2.1.6 and the current version is 2.2.18) it should be here...[image]

At least I can see it.

Comment: Very well spotted! I was having problems updating up Parse-Server via get, so I just manually downloaded the zip of the Parse-Server-Example, and then slapped my package.json, cloud code, index.js, and jsconfig.json into the example folder, and pushed all of that to Heroku. It looks like it's working now. Cheers!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You can view/edit your config parameters by using Parse RestAPI.

### To view your config parameters:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APP_ID_KEY" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: REST_API_KEY" \
  PATH_TO_PARSE_API + "/config"
```

Example:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: zirTLZa3h88Q6BBXj8WkkLxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ydcXhehk9wkz01bDBgpteVxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
  https://api.parse.com/1/config
```

### To edit your config parameters:

```
curl -X PUT \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: zirTLZa3h88Q6BBXj8WkkLxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
  -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: OXuUPDbmAWOIcYZdzUXR0prxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
  -d "{\"params\":{\"Test\":\"222\"}}" \
  https://api.parse.com/1/config
```

**NOTE:**

1. To read the config you must to set the **REST-API-KEY**
2. To edit you must set your MASTER_KEY

**Good Luck**